# Homework Question Transformation Energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, kinematics

A $1400kg$ car is approaching the hill shown in the figure at $14.0m/s$ when it suddenly runs out of gas.
[image]

What is the car's speed after coasting down the other side?

I think I have to use this equation

$mg(\Delta h)=\frac 12 m(\Delta v)^2 $

$(1400)(9.81)(\Delta h)= \frac12 (\Delta v)^2$

I am not sure if this is correct. If it is, what do I plug in for $\Delta h$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use $\Delta h$=$5m$ since it is the height by which the car descends along the course of the journey. And instead of $$mg\Delta h=\frac12 m(\Delta v)^2$$ you should rather use $$mg\Delta h=\Delta KE=\Delta (\frac12 mv^2)=\frac12 m (v_f^2-v_i^2)$$
where $v_i=14ms^{-1}$ and evaluate for $v_f$.

Comment: Oh alright, thank you I got the answer. It is 17.15m/s

Answer (score 1):

mg(∆h) = 1/2m(∆v)^2

g(∆h) = 1/2(∆v)^2

10x5 = (1/2)x(∆v)^2

∆v = 10

v in other side=24

Source:http://www.transtutors.com/homework-help/earth-science/environmental-geography/energy-transformation/